# Why do I get the error 'Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE]' with intellij and libgdx?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, libgdx

I am using Intellij for Libgdx development.Created an LIbgdx application using the libgdx setup for the release version 1.6.5 and imported it successfully into Intellij.
The desktop configuration works just fine without any errors.However, when I try to use the android configuration and install it on Nexus 4 I get the following output:

```
    Waiting for device.
    Target device: lge-nexus_4
    Uploading file
    local path: D:\D\Android\libgdx\FF\android\build\outputs\apk\android-debug.apk
   remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.mygdx.game.android
    Installing com.mygdx.game.android
    DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.mygdx.game.android"
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.mygdx.game.android
    Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE]
```

Tried to look for previously installed app from settings->apps on the device but it is nowhere to be seen.
Where Am i going wrong?This is happening for the first time with me and I did not find a solution on any other questions here.

Comment: just throwing an idea, is it possible you have two different-signed APKs in your hands? you are maybe deploying debug signed APK on a device which has the release-signed APK already installed.

Comment: Try uninstalling (manually) your game from your device and then try again.

Comment: I tried doing it manually but still couldnt! I wonder what steps exactly do i take to get rid of that problem.